# Laravel: style not fully loaded before elements causing ugly page while loading

Tags: css, laravel, pageload

**[UPDATE]**

Please not that most of these elements are loaded from the cache so no need to connect to the database which means it's not a database or server delay.

---

I'm using Laravel in my project and here's the main header code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ $lang }}" dir="@if($lang == 'ar') rtl @else ltr @endif">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="_token" id="main_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">

    <script src="<?=config("app.public_path")?>js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?=config("app.public_path")?>js/bootstrap.3.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="<?=config("app.public_path")?>js/modernizr-2.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=config("app.public_path")?>bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    @if($lang == 'ar') <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=config("app.public_path")?>css/bootstrap-rtl.css"> @endif
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=config("app.public_path")?>css/style_{{$lang}}.css">
```

And the config public path

```
'public_path' => 'http://www.example.com/public/',
```

The elements load in wrong places with wrong sizes then in seconds the stylesheet loads and elements get positiined correctly and resized too which makes the page look ugly at the beginning and I'm talking about css not javascript or jQuery. Why does this happen and how to solve it?

Comment: Normally the browser should block rendering until all pending CSS resources are loaded. The same is not true for scripts though so if you're adding classes in scripts they will not be applied on initial load.

Comment: just in case, there is 'public_path()' function if you want that... or just use asset, with which you can also set the root folder

Comment: also try to put the less JS you can in the header, put them on the bottom of the page in the order you want to load them

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `asset` function instead of PHP shorthand echo tags and config paths.

For example, instead of this:

```
<?=config("app.public_path")?>js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js
```

You are supposed to do this:

```
{{ asset('js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js') }}
```

Also, consider using `defer` for your scripts e.g.:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Comment: I did before but path was wrong on localhost and works on the server so I changed it to config path